ros2 launch fails because it can't find a Python module
I'm using ROS 2 Jazzy on Ubuntu 24.04 running on an Orange Pi 5.
When I try to ros2 launch a python launch file in my package I get an error message saying that ROS could not find a module called launch_description_sources. However, I can see the module when I check /opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/launch.
I source my workspace's local_setup.bash. If I remove all Python code from the launch file the error still happens.
Does anyone know how I can fix this? I just need to use a Python launch file to add a prefix that gives my node root access to /dev/mem. (/dev/gpiomem doesn't exist).
Here is the output I get when I try to launch something:
richmoney@richmoney-desktop:~/ros2_ws/src/wu25$ ros2 launch launcher.py
Failed to load entry point 'launch': No module named 'launch.launch_description_sources'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/jazzy/bin/ros2", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('ros2cli==0.32.1', 'console_scripts', 'ros2')())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ros2cli/cli.py", line 52, in main
    add_subparsers_on_demand(
  File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ros2cli/command/__init__.py", line 237, in add_subparsers_on_demand
    extension = command_extensions[name]
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
KeyError: 'launch'

PYTHONPATH:
richmoney@richmoney-desktop:~/ros2_ws/src/wu25$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/home/richmoney/ros2_ws/install/wu25/lib/python3.12/site-packages:/home/richmoney/ros2_ws/install/launch_testing_examples/lib/python3.12/site-packages:/home/richmoney/ros2_ws/install/examples_rclpy_pointcloud_publisher/lib/python3.12/site-packages:/home/richmoney/ros2_ws/install/examples_rclpy_minimal_subscriber/lib/python3.12/site-packages:/home/richmoney/ros2_ws/install/examples_rclpy_minimal_service/lib/python3.12/site-packages:/home/richmoney/ros2_ws/install/examples_rclpy_minimal_publisher/lib/python3.12/site-packages:/home/richmoney/ros2_ws/install/examples_rclpy_minimal_client/lib/python3.12/site-packages:/home/richmoney/ros2_ws/install/examples_rclpy_minimal_action_server/lib/python3.12/site-packages:/home/richmoney/ros2_ws/install/examples_rclpy_minimal_action_client/lib/python3.12/site-packages:/home/richmoney/ros2_ws/install/examples_rclpy_guard_conditions/lib/python3.12/site-packages:/home/richmoney/ros2_ws/install/examples_rclpy_executors/lib/python3.12/site-packages:/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.12/site-packages

I don't have a setup.py file if that means anything.

Did you append your launch folder to CMakeLists.txt? If you didn't, please add this lines to your CMake and do colcon build --symlink-install again.
install(DIRECTORY
    launch
    config
    DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}/
)

Additional, I think you should call launch file via ros2 launch package_name package_name.launch.py command.

Yeah, I have this in my CMakeLists.txt and double-checked the command variation and it still isn't enough to make it work. I think there's something wrong with my ros installation. The error happens even without any Python code in the file.

Did you source the ROS workspace?
source /opt/ros/jazzy/setup.bash

Check also if you have a package named "launch" in your workspace that could create some conflicts

Yeah, I already had my overlay sourced before I did anything. And yeah there's no launch package.

I just noticed that you used the command ros2 launch launcher.py while the correct command should be ros2 launch PACKAGE_NAME LAUNCH_FILE
